# Symbol for a "twisted product"?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am trying to make a symbol for a "twisted product".  I've tried stackrel:

```
$A \mathbin{\stackrel{\sim}{\times}} B$
```

but the sim floats too high above the times, causing unpleasant line spacing.  I've also tried widetilde

```
$A \mathbin{\widetilde{\times}} B$
```

but it has the same problem.  Ideally I'd like the tilde to have the same width as the times and for the spacing between the two to be pretty tight.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: I tried detexify and looking at the CTAN list.  No joy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/) didn't help, so maybe you really have to do it yourself:

```
\newcommand\simtimes{\mathbin{%
    \stackrel{\sim}{\smash{\times}\rule{0pt}{0.9ex}}%
    }}
```

Adjust the `0.9ex` to your needs.

Comment: Perfect.  I used 0.6ex.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

The parameters 0.7 and 0.3 might be needed adjustment if used with different fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% a general purpose macro
\newcommand{\xmathpalette}[2]{\mathchoice
  {#1\displaystyle\textfont{#2}}%
  {#1\textstyle\textfont{#2}}%
  {#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont{#2}}%
  {#1\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptfont{#2}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twistedproduct}{%
  \mathbin{\xmathpalette\twisted@product\relax}%
}

\newcommand{\twisted@product}[3]{%
  \vbox{%
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      \scalebox{0.7}{$\m@th#1\sim$}\cr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-0.3\fontdimen5 #2 2}
      $\m@th#1\times$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$S^2\twistedproduct S^2$ $X_{\twistedproduct_{\twistedproduct}}$

\end{document}
```

The macro `\xmathpalette` is an extension of `\mathpalette` that makes also the font in the current style (`\textfont`, `\scriptfont` or `\scriptscriptfont`). In this case we use it to access the x-height of the symbol font for the current style.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For slightly improved spacing displayed and inline, you can use `\ooalign`. The code is

```
\newcommand{\twprod}{\mathbin{%
    \ooalign{\raise1.15ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\sim$}\cr\hidewidth$\times$\hidewidth\cr}%
    }}
```

[image]

If you will ever use the symbol in a subscript or superscript, `\mathchoice` allows for greatly improved spacing in scriptstyle. The height of the `\sim` is easily adjustable by changing the `1.15ex` for display and inline, `.85ex` for script and (though I can't imagine using it) `.65ex` for scriptscript.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\twprod}{\mathbin{\mathchoice%
    {\ooalign{\raise1.15ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\sim$}\cr\hidewidth$\times$\hidewidth\cr}}%
    {\ooalign{\raise1.15ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\sim$}\cr\hidewidth$\times$\hidewidth\cr}}%
    {\ooalign{\raise.85ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\sim$}\cr\hidewidth$\scriptstyle\times$\hidewidth\cr}}%
    {\ooalign{\raise.65ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\sim$}\cr\hidewidth$\scriptscriptstyle\times$\hidewidth\cr}}%   
    }}

\begin{document}

$S^2\twprod S^2\quad F_{S^2\twprod S^2}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown, `\ttimes` has the same spacing as `\times`.  It adjusts automatically to the math style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\ttimes{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-1\LMpt}{\SavedStyle\times}
  {\SavedStyle_{\hstretch{.9}{\mkern1mu\sim}}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}}
\begin{document}
$ A\ttimes C$\par
$ A\times C$\par
$ \scriptstyle A\ttimes C$\par
$ \scriptstyle A\times C$\par
$ \scriptscriptstyle A\ttimes C$\par
$ \scriptscriptstyle A\times C$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]