# Use of ~ (\tilde) on the top of Capital letters

Tags: symbols

For small letters a,b,c,d, we can put ~ on the top of these letters by

```
\tilde{a}, \tilde{b}, \tilde{c}, etc.
```

and they are clearly visible in the output. But, while putting them on *Capital* letters A,B,C,D, it is not so clearly visible in the output, i.e. by the commands

```
\tilde{A}, \tilde{B}, \tilde{C}, etc.
```

the symbol ~ on the top of these letters appears to be small compared to them. 
How can we enlarge it? or is there any other way to put sufficiently large ~ on the top of the Capital letters?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Type `\widetilde{A}`, `\widetilde{B}`, `\widetilde{C}`, etc. to get wider tilde symbols.

Comment: Incidentally, `\widetilde` is available in both in LaTeX and PlainTeX.

Comment: Unfortunately, `\widetilde{X}` does not look nice to me. The tilde is _very_ wide, and it also does not appear to be centered well. Currently looking for a nice alternative...

Comment: @jhin - I'm afraid I cannot address your query meaningfully without knowing which math font you employ. Please provide more information about your document setup.

Comment: oh wow, actually, I was not expecting such a swift reply. To be honest, now that I look at it again, maybe everything is alright? I don't know, my equations just look "crowded" with it. Maybe because it's interfering with the transpose "T"? Here's a small example: 
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\begin{document}
$$(\widetilde{X}^T\widetilde{X})^{-1}\widetilde{X}^Ty$$
\end{document}`

Comment: @jhin - Speaking for myself here (obviously): I think the main problem is not with the `\widetilde{X}` but wih the use of `^T` to denote (matrix) transposes. I'd use either `'` ("prime") or a dedicated macro called, say, `\transp` (see, e.g., the definition below). `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{stix2} \newcommand\transp{^{\scriptscriptstyle\top}\!} \begin{document}
$\displaystyle  (\widetilde{X}^T\widetilde{X})^{-1}\widetilde{X}^Ty \quad (\widetilde{X}\transp\widetilde{X})^{-1}\widetilde{X}\transp y \quad (\widetilde{X}'\widetilde{X})^{-1}\widetilde{X}'y $
\end{document} `

Comment: @jhin - For more information on the subject of transpose operators in a Latex document, please see [What is the best symbol for vector/matrix transpose?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30619/5001) Clearly, there is no consensus on what might be the "best" symbol. My recommendation: Make an informed choice and stick with it. :-) By the way, if you define `\transp` as a macro, you give yourself an easy path toward changing the appearance of the transpose operator should you ever feel a need to do so.

Comment: thanks, that was really helpful! I'm now using another symbol for the transpose, but I also opted for this less wide tilde version: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24888/64293

Comment: @jhin - Glad to hear you found a satisfactory solution.