# Large tilde over math symbol with automatic horizontal positioning

Tags: math-mode, accents

I find that `$\tilde{x}` produces a tilde that is much too small for legibility at the screen resolution I normally use for reading. On my screen it looks like a tiny bar above the symbol. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24881/widetilde-is-too-big-and-tilde-is-too-small-is-there-something-between) asked how to generate a larger tilde over a particular wide character (a mathcal W), presumably with the motivation of making the tilde look better matched in size with this large glyph. The answer by Ant provides a couple of methods, which look good for wide characters but bad for narrow ones. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tildea}[1]{\overset{\sim}{#1}}
\newcommand{\tildeb}[1]{\stackrel{\sim}{\smash{#1}\rule{0pt}{1.1ex}}}

$\tilde{W} \quad \tildea{W} \quad \tildeb{W}$

$\tilde{I} \quad \tildea{I} \quad \tildeb{I}$

\end{document}
```

Results:

[image: rendered output of latex code]

To me the larger tildes over the "I" look like they're way off in terms of horizontal positioning. Is there a way to make a macro that automagically gets this horizontal positioning right, as the `\tilde` macro seems to do? I would like to avoid having different macros for characters of different widths.

Comment: Perhaps `\widetilde`?

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I hadn't even noticed that possibility, which was mentioned in the linked question. I think that works well enough for my purposes. It does look kind of goofy on a character as wide as W, but I don't actually use it atop a W.

Comment: or really really wide tilde https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode/63549#63549

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest to use the `lite` version of `mtpro2` that you can find to CTAN. Here for example there is a recent [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/mtpro2.pdf) (see pag. 14). Is you will use this MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

Let $\wwtilde{I}$ collision be elastic in one frame of reference.\\
Let $\tilde{I}$ and let $ \widetilde{I}$ another frame.

\end{document}
```

you will obtain this output.

[image]

The best tilde is with the command `\wwtilde` a good solution to center it with any letter. Personally I suggest to leave the same size (or dimension) of "tilde".