# Vertically scale accent, but keep distance to symbol equal

Tags: accents, scaling, tilde, scalebox

I need a `\tilde` which is a little more noticeable, why I tried [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24881/widetilde-is-too-big-and-tilde-is-too-small-is-there-something-between/24885) in combination with `scalebox`. However, together with the vertical scaling, also the vertical distance between the symbol and the accent increases. How can I avoid that? I tried `\smash` and `raisebox` which had no effect.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\vartilde}[1]{\accentset{\smash{\scalebox{0.8}[1.4]{\ensuremath{\sim}}}}{#1}}

\begin{document}    

$ \tilde{q}^{\,+|-}_j $ \quad vs. \quad $ \vartilde{q}^{\,+|-}_j $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the vertical white space around `\sim`. You can use the `\trimbox` command from the `trimclip` package to make the adjustment:

[image]

If you want more space between the `\sim` and the letter below, *decrease* the value `.3ex` in the `\trimbox` command.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\vartilde}[1]{\accentset{\scalebox{0.8}[1.4]{\trimbox{0pt .3ex}{\ensuremath{\sim}}}}{#1}}

\begin{document}    

$ \tilde{q}^{\,+|-}_j $ \quad vs. \quad $ \vartilde{q}^{\,+|-}_j $

\end{document}
```

Note that the accent will not scale if it appears in scriptstyle or scriptscriptstyle. If you need those, you can use `\mathchoice`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\vartilde}[1]{\mathchoice
{\accentset{\scalebox{0.8}[1.4]{\trimbox{0pt .3ex}{\ensuremath{\sim}}}}{#1}}
{\accentset{\scalebox{0.8}[1.4]{\trimbox{0pt .3ex}{\ensuremath{\sim}}}}{#1}}
{\accentset{\scalebox{0.6}[1]{\trimbox{0pt .3ex}{\ensuremath{\sim}}}}{#1}}
{\accentset{\scalebox{0.4}[.7]{\trimbox{0pt .3ex}{\ensuremath{\sim}}}}{#1}}
}
```

[image]

You can adjust the scaling and spacing for each style however you like.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `\widetilde`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\vartilde}[1]{\accentset{\smash{\scalebox{0.8}[1.4]{\ensuremath{\sim}}}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

$ \tilde{q}^{\,+|-}_j $ \quad vs. \quad $ \vartilde{q}^{\,+|-}_j $\quad vs. \quad $ \widetilde{q}^{\,+|-}_j $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it does not really answer the question. `\widetilde` is better than nothing, but still too close to `\overline`. I have to avoid that the reader oversees the difference between these two at a glance. That is why I stretched it quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\vbox{\hbox{...}\kern-1pt}` construction:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\vartilde}[1]
    {\accentset{\scalebox{.8}[1.4]{\vbox{\hbox{$\sim$}\kern-1pt}}}{#1}}
```