# How to create this symbol

Tags: symbols

I[image]

I want to create this symbol. any one help me.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: \tiltedandextremelyblurryx if I remember right

Comment: There are votes to close as exact duplicate, but that symbol seems unknown both to deTeXify and the comprehensive symbols list. I have certainly never seen it before. I don't think such a symbol exists; one could perhaps fake it by using a division sign overlaid with a rule, however.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen `\XSolidBrush` from [`bbding`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bbding) or `\ding{55}` from [`pifont`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pifont), both in the [comprehensive symbols list](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), seem to come reasonably close (but are apparently not included in the [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/symbols.html) symbol table).

Comment: I agree with @Harald.  What is a user to do when they want a specific symbol that does not appear in deTeXify or the comprehensive list?  A good example is the [twisted product](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12579/symbol-for-a-twisted-product) symbol, which needs a DIY solution.  I've never seen the (very blurry) symbol requested by OP, but if it's for a specific purpose it may deserve an answer beyond the approximations offered by @diabonas.  Here is a possibility: `\ooalign{\hfil/\hfil\cr\hfil\rule[-.2ex]{.5pt}{1.6ex}\hfil\cr}`.