Centering a letter under \t (tie-after accent)
I would like the shape of the \t{t} (tie-after accent) but I want the placement to be more like \hat{t}.  Does anyone know a way to do this.

Welcome to the TEX.SE.

You might do like the following, but why?
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\T}{m}{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip\check@mathfonts
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \sbox\z@{\the\textfont1\char127}%
      \hidewidth\hspace*{-2.3\wd\z@}\box\z@\hidewidth\cr
      \noalign{\kern-1ex}%
      #1\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\T{t}\quad \T{u}\quad \T{A}

x\T{\i}x\quad d\T{\i}b

\end{document}


If you also want a math accent,
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\T}{m}{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip\check@mathfonts
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \sbox\z@{\the\textfont1\char127}%
      \hidewidth\hspace*{-2.3\wd\z@}\box\z@\hidewidth\cr
      \noalign{\kern-1ex}%
      #1\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tieaccent}{m}{%
  {\xmathpalette\tieaccent@{#1}}%
}
% a general purpose macro https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480801/4427
\newcommand{\xmathpalette}[2]{\mathchoice
  {#1\displaystyle\textfont{#2}}%
  {#1\textstyle\textfont{#2}}%
  {#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont{#2}}%
  {#1\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptfont{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\tieaccent@}[3]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \sbox\z@{$#1\mathchar"17F$}%
      \hidewidth\kern-0.2\wd\z@\box\z@\hidewidth\cr
      \noalign{\kern-\fontdimen5 #2 1}%
      $#1#3$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\T{t}\quad \T{u}\quad \T{A}

x\T{\i}x\quad d\T{\i}b

$\tieaccent{x}+\tieaccent{A}$

$\scriptstyle\tieaccent{x}+\tieaccent{A}$

\end{document}


A totally different strategy is to use a proper accent that's found in the Cyrillic encodings.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareTextAccent{\f}{T2A}{18}
\DeclareTextAccentDefault{\f}{T2A}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrhelper}{T2A}{\familydefault}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\tieaccent}{\mathord}{cyrhelper}{18}

\begin{document}

\f{t}\quad \f{u}\quad \f{A}

x\f{\i}x\quad d\f{\i}b

$\tieaccent{x}+\tieaccent{A}$

$\scriptstyle\tieaccent{x}+\tieaccent{A}$

\end{document}

If your font family supports Cyrillic, I'd go this way.

If using a Unicode engine, you can do it as well.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontsetup}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% the inverted breve is not a common accent
% so we need to help LaTeX
\DeclareUnicodeAccent{\f}{"0311}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tieaccent}{m}{%
  \Umathaccent fixed 7\symoperators "00311\scan_stop: #1
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\f{t}\quad \f{u}\quad \f{A}

x\f{\i}x\quad d\f{\i}b

$\tieaccent{x}+\tieaccent{A}$

$\scriptstyle\tieaccent{x}+\tieaccent{A}$

\end{document}


